# regex: if a line doesn't start with a particular string, add it as prefix

Tags: regex, string, prefix

I've this text:

```
£££££Ciao a tutti§§§§§,§§§§§2009§§§§§,§§§§§8§§§§§
£££££Il mio nome è Geltry§§§§§,§§§§§2009§§§§§,§§§§§6§§§§§
Bla bla bla§§§§§,§§§§§2010§§§§§,§§§§§7§§§§§
£££££Le amiche della sposa§§§§§,§§§§§2011§§§§§,§§§§§3§§§§§
```

With TextCrawler I find all the lines that have not £££££ as a prefix, so:

```
^((?!£££££).)*$
```

What I should write as replacement?

```
Reg Ex: ^((?!£££££).)*$
Replacement: ?  <-- what write here?
```

to have:

```
£££££Ciao a tutti§§§§§,§§§§§2009§§§§§,§§§§§8§§§§§
£££££Il mio nome è Geltry§§§§§,§§§§§2009§§§§§,§§§§§6§§§§§
£££££Bla bla bla§§§§§,§§§§§2010§§§§§,§§§§§7§§§§§
£££££Le amiche della sposa§§§§§,§§§§§2011§§§§§,§§§§§3§§§§§
```

Comment: Which language? The semantics are not 100% universal. You might want to try `inputString.replace(/(^£{5})/,'£££££');`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Search:

```
^(?!£££££)(.+)$
```

Replace:

```
£££££$1
```

First, your regex was incorrect. `^((?!£££££).)*$` matches a line that doesn't contain `£££££` *anywhere*.  It also captures only the last character of the line, where you want it to capture the whole line.

My regex matches only lines that don't *start with* `£££££`.  It captures the whole line in group number one, and (according to [the manual](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler/manual)), the `$1` in the replacement string reinserts the captured text.

I also changed the `*` to `+` so it won't match empty lines and replace them with `£££££`.

Comment: PAY ATTENTION: in TextCrawler, set MULTILINE ANCHOR to 'ON'

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to capture anything, just insert if the line doesn't start with `£££££`:

Search: `^(?!£££££)`

Replace: `£££££`

If you're not matching one line at a time, you also need to ensure that it's a multiline search.

Comment: Right, but Alan Moore solution won't keep empty lines. It know that it was not a specification in my question, but his suggestion is right what I need :-)
+1 4U

Answer (score 1):

You can use `()` to match subexpression:

```
( subexpression )
Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number.

(? subexpression)
Captures the matched subexpression into a named group.
```

so your Regex can be like:

```
(^(?:(?!£££££).)*$)
//or
(?<line>^(?:(?!£££££).)*$)
```

and for replacement:

```
$ number
Substitutes the substring matched by group number.

${ name }
Substitutes the substring matched by the named group name.
```

your replacement can be like this:

```
£££££$1
//or
£££££${line}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this regexp: `^(((?!£££££).)*)$`

Write this as replacement: `£££££^(\1)$`

`\1` will be the source match, that in your case it is the whole row.